# Error on the soap xml data return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, soap, savon

I am sending the below xml to soap but it gives error;

```
SOAPAction: "getTranslations", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 583
D, [2017-12-13T23:09:32.171362 #59367] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:pos="http://cbm.mmk.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins0="http://rmi.java" xmlns:ins1="http://lang.java">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <pos:getTranslations>
      <pos:userId>1234</pos:userId>
      <pos:username>support@gmail.com</pos:username>
      <pos:password>123456</pos:password>
      <pos:root>
        <pos:element id="items">12:3456789</pos:element>
      </pos:root>
    </pos:getTranslations>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then it returns an error about the nested exception;

```
: SOAP response (status 500)
D, [2017-12-13T23:09:32.580270 #59367] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Could not read XML stream.. Nested exception is com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Expected a text token, got START_ELEMENT.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,492]</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <errorcode>-1</errorcode>
        <errormessage>Could not read XML stream.. Nested exception is com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Expected a text token, got START_ELEMENT.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,492]</errormessage>
      </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I did not understand the error, I have checked gyoku then used custom attributes in Savon gem. What is the wrong part?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

This is the function I would like to use in the documentation;

```
public String getTranslations(long _userId,String _username,String _password,String
_xmlValues) throws RemoteException;

<!--REQUEST-->
<root>
     <element id=”items”>24:123456789,24:987654321</element>
     <element id=”languages”>de,hr</element>
</root>
<!--RESPONSE -->
<root>
  <item id="24:123456789">
    <translation lang="de" value="12V Kühlschrank" />
    <translation lang="hr" value="12V kuhalo" />
  </item>
  <item id="24:987654321">
<translation lang="hr" value="Pomoćni čamac" /> </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Is the password a string or a MD5 hash?

Comment: password is just a string and it works for API's other services/functions